# Bookshelf.js fetchAll() performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, bookshelf.js, fetchall

I have +20k records in my MySQL table that uses InnoDB engine and utf8_general comparison.
When I am trying to fetch all the data using Bookshelf.js [fetchAll()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKn5N.png) it takes around 6 seconds.
I tried using knex directly which takes ~200ms. Does anyone know why it might take so long for Bookshelf.js?